# why is java accepting unicode outside the " " and ' ' also?

Tags: java

This line compiles fine

```
Thread t = \u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u0054\u0068\u0072\u0065\u0061\u0064\u0028\u0029\u003B
```

this is the unicode for the text `new Thread();`

my question is what is the need for accepting unicode characters outside the `" "` or `' '`. we can use unicodes in string literals and character literals. but what is the need for it to be accepted in the actual code itself?

Comment: may I know which editor you used?

Comment: One use would be to be able to call a method containing non-ascii characters from a class whose source code is in ASCII. But I've never seen it used in practice.

Comment: @StalinGino : i used a notepad and windows command prompt

Comment: Because, my jDeveloper IDE couldn't understand the unicode. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @StalinGino :it may be an encoding problem in your JDeveloper, there are two place to set encoding: 1st is in Tools>Preferences, to set the editor encoding. 2nd is in project properties>Compiler, to set the encoding to compile java file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this works is that the Unicode escape sequence isn't handled by the grammar or the string parsing code but the tokenizer. So the Java grammar never "sees" those escape sequences, it gets a Unicode string.

Which has unfortunate side effects like this code doesn't compile:

```
// C:\user\...
```

For most of us, it's a comment. For the tokenizer, it's the illegal unicode sequence `ser\`.

The reason to do it this way is that you can now use any Unicode character anywhere in the Java source code - Java identifiers are *not* limited to ASCII!

But the tools to edit Java might not be as good. In 1994, it was pretty hard to find a text editor capable of Unicode. Also, code generators often work better if you stay with ASCII.

Comment: saw an example similar to this in the book "Java Puzzlers - Traps, Pitfalls, And Corner Cases by Joshua bloch". thx for the answer.. :)

Answer (score 4):

[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) specified it

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code unit (§3.1) of the indicated hexadecimal value
>
> **This transformed version is equally acceptable to a Java compiler and represents the exact same program.** The exact Unicode source can later be restored from this ASCII form by converting each escape sequence where multiple u's are present to a sequence of Unicode characters with one fewer u, while simultaneously converting each escape sequence with a single u to the corresponding single Unicode character.

Comment: thx for the JLS link. but what is the specific need for this?

Comment: **It's just also**, `recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters` ,along with direct `ASCII` characters

Answer (score 2):

This works because the Java Language Specification requires this. See [3.3. Unicode Escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code unit (§3.1) of the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other characters unchanged. Representing supplementary characters requires two consecutive Unicode escapes. This translation step results in a sequence of Unicode input characters.

The reason is simple: Java allows full unicode support (even for identifiers!), but sometimes it is not practical to use actual unicode for your source files, in that case you can use escapes.

This also means that unicode escapes are not an artifact of strings in Java, but actually of the compiler: if you have a `String` (or `char`) with unicode escapes it will translated at compiletime to the actual character, not at runtime!

The section [3.2. Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) is also relevant:

> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of Unicode escapes (§3.3) in the raw stream of Unicode characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape of the form `\uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is `xxxx`. This translation step allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.
> 2. A translation of the Unicode stream resulting from step 1 [...]

Comment: but apart from naming identifiers, is there any other use for these?

Comment: @BlackPanther I don't understand your question. Java is fully unicode, so they provide a mechanism to support that even if your editor or other tools don't support it. Remember: in the '90s unicode support was a lot less developed than now.

Answer (score 1):

If the *source code* is not UTF-8 this feature makes it possible to use Unicode characters in the source code otherwise not available

Comment: but apart from naming identifiers, is there any other use for these?